# MULTIPLE INSERT OVERWRITE in HIVE

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to do multiple insert overwrite in Hive by the following commands.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE  table results_3 SELECT NULL, res, NULL, NULL FROM results where field= 'title';
```

And the content of results_3 table after the first command

```
NULL    Up On Cripple Creek (2000 Digital Remaster) NULL    NULL
NULL    The Weight (2000 Digital Remaster)  NULL    NULL
NULL    Rhythm Of The Rain (LP Version) NULL    NULL
NULL    Who'll Stop the Rain    NULL    NULL
NULL    I Walk the Line NULL    NULL
NULL    Against The Wind    NULL    NULL
NULL    Lyin' Eyes  NULL    NULL
NULL    North To Alaska NULL    NULL
NULL    You Gave Me A Mountain  NULL    NULL
NULL    Night Moves NULL    NULL


INSERT OVERWRITE  table results_3 SELECT NULL, NULL, res, NULL FROM results where field= 'albums';
```

And the content of results_3 table after the second command

```
NULL    NULL    The Band    NULL
NULL    NULL    The Band    NULL
NULL    NULL    The Cascades    NULL
NULL    NULL    Creedence Clearwater Revival    NULL
NULL    NULL    Johnny Cash NULL
NULL    NULL    Bob Seger   NULL
NULL    NULL    The Eagles  NULL
NULL    NULL    Johnny Horton   NULL
NULL    NULL    Marty Robbins   NULL
NULL    NULL    Bob Seger   NULL
```

but I want to merge the two things together. Do you have any idea how I can tackle this?

Thanks

Comment: How do you match up the rows which should be merged? What are the schemas for your tables? If there is an id in the results table then you could perform a JOIN.

Answer (score 3):

You can append in such way:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE
select col1 ... col2 
from 
(
SELECT col1 ... coln from TABLE  --old data
UNION ALL
SELECT col1 ... col2n from TABLE2 --new data
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hive `insert` does not support append so far.

A simple way : `insert overwrite` two directory. Merge it manually.
Or
`insert into` a table with different partition(But, in fact different partition have different directory).

Plz see [hive wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingdataintoHiveTablesfromqueries) for more information.

Comment: `hadoop dfs -mv <sourcefile> <destinationfile>` or `hadoop dfs -getmerge`